# Adding database name before a query to transfer data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server, I was planning to insert data from 4 tables of database name 'A' to another database 'B'.

I wrote the below query:

```
DECLARE @SourceDB as NVARCHAR(255)='665DB33AS1'
DECLARE @DestDB as NVARCHAR(255)='755DB33Ab2'
DECLARE @SourceDID as NVARCHAR(255)='121sdfsdf1212sfw'

INSERT INTO @DestDB.[ABC104].[Document]([DID], [LocalID], [Extension], [Content])
SELECT [DID], [LocalID], [Extension], [Content]
FROM @SourceDB .[ABC104].[Document]
WHERE [DID] = =@SourceDID)
```

But here am not getting the Source and Destination database name replaced correctly.

Please help.

Comment: You can't carry out regular SQL statements on variable table or database names. You need to use dynamic SQL (google will help - its a complex subject).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `DYNAMIC SQL`

```
DECLARE @DestDB as NVARCHAR(255)='755DB33Ab2'
DECLARE @SourceDID as NVARCHAR(255)='121sdfsdf1212sfw'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL=CONCAT('INSERT INTO', @DestDB,'.[ABC104].[Document]([DID], [LocalID], [Extension], [Content])
SELECT [DID], [LocalID], [Extension], [Content] FROM',@SourceDB,' .[ABC104].[Document] WHERE [DID] = ',@SourceDID)

SELECT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of code seems highly suspicious.  What is being stored in different databases seems like it should be stored in a single database -- probably in a single table.

But sometimes this is necessary.

You need dynamic SQL.  I would recommend:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = '
INSERT INTO @DestDB.[ABC104].[Document]([DID], [LocalID], [Extension], [Content])
    SELECT [DID], [LocalID], [Extension], [Content]
    FROM @SourceDB.[ABC104].[Document]
    WHERE [DID] = @SourceDID
';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@DestDB', @DestDb);       -- might want quotename
SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@SourceDB', @SourceDB);   -- might want quotename

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                   'N@SourceDID NVARCHAR(255)',
                   @SourceDID=@SourceDID;
```

Note that this replaces the identifiers using `REPLACE()`.  It does this in multiple steps, so it is easy to see what is being replaced.

Also, this does not replace `@SourceDID`, because that is just a comparison value which a parameterized query can readily handle.

I didn't throw in `QUOTENAME()`, but when inserting names of things, it is a best practice, particularly if the data is coming from a less than 100% secure source.